# MySQL multiple insert statements in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to run multiple insert statements based on condition in phpmyadmin through stored procedure. I am not able to run more than two insert statements through stored procedure, it ignores other statements and executes only first two, I am not getting what is causing the issue. I am posting my code here.

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BULKINSERT`() 
 BEGIN  
    DECLARE company_id,department_id BIGINT;
    SELECT id INTO company_id FROM COMPANIES WHERE Name="Company 1" ; 
    IF company_id is null THEN 
            INSERT INTO companies(Name) VALUES("Company 1") ; 
            SET company_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
    SELECT id INTO department_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE Name="Support 1" ; 
    IF department_id IS NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS(Name,company_id) VALUES("Support 1",company_id) ;  
        SET department_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
    SELECT id INTO department_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE Name="Finance" ; 
    IF department_id IS NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS(Name,company_id) VALUES("Finance",company_id) ;  
        SET department_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
    SELECT id INTO department_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE Name="Digital" ; 
    IF department_id IS NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS(Name,company_id) VALUES("Digital",company_id) ;  
        SET department_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
    SELECT id INTO department_id FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE Name="BI TEST" ; 
    IF department_id IS NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS(Name,company_id) VALUES("BI TEST",company_id) ;  
        SET department_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
 END $$ 
 DELIMITER ;
```

In the above code only first company 'Company 1' and first department 'Support 1' get updated. The control terminates after that. I am not getting why is this happening. Is there any limitation of running queries in MYSQL stored procedure ?

Thanks in Advance,
Amar

Comment: Try clearing `department_id` before reusing it in the next select

Comment: Why do you need the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from `INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS`? You never use that.

Comment: Thanks, @RiggsFolly I saw your comment and re-read my code line by line and realized what was wrong. It was very silly mistake, as deparment_id is not null how can it pass if condition, I set it to null and now it is working fine.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the `SELECT` doesn't match anything it never assigns to the `department_id` variable, so it keeps its value from the previous `INSERT`.

If `Name` is a unique key in the table, you can use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert all the names that don't already exist.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `BULKINSERT`() 
 BEGIN  
    DECLARE company_id BIGINT;
    SELECT id INTO company_id FROM COMPANIES WHERE Name="Company 1" ; 
    IF company_id is null THEN 
            INSERT INTO companies(Name) VALUES("Company 1") ; 
            SET company_id=LAST_INSERT_ID() ; 
    END IF ; 
    INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS (Name, company_id) VALUES
    ("Support 1", company_id),
    ("Finance", company_id),
    ("Digital", company_id),
    ("BI TEST", company_id);
END %%
DELIMITER ;
```